VBA to copy formatted data from one cell to manuallly selected destination
I'm new to VBA and after a half hour of combing the web, I haven't found a solution. I'd like create a macro for Excel which will copy data with formatting from one cell to a destination that can be selected manually at run time. If someone could share a simple method, I'd appreciate it.
For example, in the embedded graphic, I want to create macros for each individual cell in A1, B1, C1 that will allow a user to select any cell in a single worksheet manually and use a ctrl+[letter] shortcut to paste the appropriate value into that cell. Many thanks in advance.

I tried using the record macro tool, but I can't see a way to create a paste action that's destination-agnostic.

Something like ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Odyssey City-Town_F...").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=ActiveCell?

 each individual cell in A1, B1, C1 - Do you mean A1,A2,A3? paste the appropriate value into that cell What's the appropriate value?
